# how to refer base methods in inherited class without advancing to the next line if redirect occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have an Index controller, where i check if the logged-in user is an admin or not:

```
       public ActionResult Index()
        { 
            if (Session["Admin"].ToString() != "True")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MainPage");
            }
            SetUID();
            ... (few more codes to grab the view list to return to Index View)
            ...
            return View(vml);
        }
```

The issue is I have many controllers that i have to check this and I thought i could put this method in a base controller that is inherited in this controller.

To be clear, I tried to bundle up this (if condition to check if admin) method that redirects to "processpayment" controller if not an admin, but it comes back to this Index method after  after checking this method in the base controller , whether admin or not, and goes for the next line - SetUID();

How do i prevent this , to not go to this line, if a user is not an admin, and be redirected permanently to "MainPage" ?

But I am not sure how to accomplish this in my base controller, so that i could refer that method alone in the all the controllers that would check for this condition.

Comment: No, your action should not be hit if user is not authorized. Looks like you should be doing  MVC's custom authoritation filters instead. Here you have a sample [Custom auth filter - csharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-authorization-filter-in-mvc-with-an-example/)

Comment: Thanks @Cleptus, will go through this documentation.